# Setup Server to Server in Firebase and GA4

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-4, server-to-server

I'm trying to setup S2S in Firebase for connect data Service Applications and GA4 purpose.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2p7g.png)

For application, we have an android and iOS, for sure we aslo have 2 firebase_id/secret_key: 1 for android and another ones for IOS

In case user purchase in website, we need to fill firebase_id and secret_key data to connect web-app. Do I use Android ID or iOS ID? or another?

I'm trying to setup only android but it maybe lost some data for iOS